# lightGallery - как сделать чтобы при наведении мыши затемнялась миниатюра и появлялась на ней лупа

Tags: jquery, анимация, gallery, lightbox

На любом примере демо-версий при наведении мыши миниатюра затемняется, чуть приближается изображение и появляется лупа.
До нажатия на миниатюру должен произойти эффект!
Тут во всех демках этот эффект по умолчанию, 
http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/

А у меня сейчас так: 
http://veter61.ru/gallery.php

При наведении мыши на миниатюру ничего не происходит!
В остальном галерея работает как надо.

В документации не нашел, как это сделать. Вот документация:

thumbnail plugin я подключил.

Вот мой код:
Подключения lightgallery (скрипты, стили):

```js
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightgallery.css">
<script src="js/lightgallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lg-thumbnail.min.js"></script>
```

Инициализация:

```js
     <script>    
   $(function () {
    $("#lightgallery").lightGallery({ showThumbByDefault: true });
   });
        </script>
```

Comment: А что вам мешает в инспекторе просмотреть код из примера и скопировать его?

Comment: через инспектор смотрел. ни одного обработчика события наведения на мышь не обнаружил нигде на странице, даже на родительских по отношению к img элементах

Comment: через инспектор вроде нашел как картинку затемнить. а вот как ее увеличить немного пока не понял

Comment: увеличение делается на css через transform:scale(), без js

Comment: да, спасибо, разберусь наверное сам